# Python Autocomplete Variable Name

Tags: python, variables, autocomplete

I am new to Python and want an auto-completing variable inside a while-loop. I try to give a minimal example. Lets assume I have the following files in my folder, each starting with the same letters and an increasing number but the end of the filenames consists of just random numbers

```
a_i=1_404
a_i=2_383
a_i=3_180
```

I want a while loop like

```
while 1 <= 3:
    old_timestep     = 'a_i=n_*'
    actual_timestep  = 'a_i=(n+1)_*' 
    ... (some functions that need the filenames saved in the two above initialised variables)
    n = n+1
```

So if I start the loop I want it to automatically process all files in my directory. As a result there are two questions:

1) How do I tell python that (in my example I used the '*') I want the filename to be completed automatically?

2) How to I use a formula inside the filename (in my example the '(n+1)')?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve 1) myself by first doing a) then b):

1) a) Truncate the file names so that only the first x characters are left:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    cp a_i=$((i))_* a_i=$((i))
done
```

b)

```
n = 1
while n <= 3:
    old = 'a_i=' + str(n) 
    new = 'a_i=' + str(n+1)
```

the str() is for converting the integer n into a string in order to concatenate 
thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

1) To my knowledge you can't do that automatically. I would store all filenames in the directory in a list and then do a search through that list

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
dir_files = [ f for f in listdir('.') if isfile(join('.',f)) ]
while i <= 3:
    old_timestep = "a_i=n_"
    for f in dir_files:
        if f.startswith(old_timestep):
            # process file
    i += 1
```

2) You can use string concatenation

```
f = open("a_i=" + str(n + 1) + "remainder of filename", 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/glob.html) module to do `*` expansion:

```
import glob
old = next(glob.glob('a_i={}_*'.format(n)))
actual = next(glob.glob('a_i={}_*'.format(n + 1)))
```

Comment: I get following error message:  """"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 34, in <module>
    surf_sol_old = next(glob.glob('a_i={}_*'.format(o_timer)))
ValueError: zero length field name in format""""

Comment: use a more up to date version of python